# Make Python module callable at command line after pip install

Tags: python, module, pip

What is required to be able to call a module by its name after it has been released on pip?

I saw another answer which explains how we can run modules locally, but I'm interested in how one can facilitate others with their package through exposure from pip.

If anyone needs an example, lets say we want to have `ppp` "pip python printer"; the only requirement for the package would be after installing `ppp`, someone can call `ppp` which would print `1` to the terminal.

Comment: Per Google: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

Comment: @Alexander That is the perfect extensive answer.